# Redirection after post request

Tags: html, node.js

I am creating a very simple website with a form in it. 
I have a problem to redirect to a page after doing the post request.

I have tried many things I found on Stackoverflaw but I can't manage to make it work.
This is the error I get :

Error: Cannot find module 'html'

HTML :

```
  <form action="/LUNProvisionning" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>LUN Provisionning</legend>
      <br />
      <label>Choix du serveur : </label>
      <select id="serveur" name="serveur">
        <option value="1">Pas de detection de serveur :'(</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <label>Volumétrie en Go 5 - 1000 : </label>
      <input type="number" min="5" max="1000" value="500" name="volumetrie">
      <br />
      <label>Type de provisionning : </label>
      <select id="provisionning" name="type">
        <option value="1">Thin</option>
        <option value="2">Deco</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Nodejs:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
app.use('/', router);

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html'));
});

router.get('/VMProvisionning', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '\/public/views/VMProvisionning.html'));
});

router.get('/LUNProvisionning', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/views/LUNProvisionning.html'));
});

app.post("/VMProvisionning", function (request, response) {
    console.log(request.body.environnement);
    console.log(request.body.vCPU);
    console.log(request.body.RAM);
    console.log(request.body.tailledisque);
    response.render("\VMProvisionning.html");
});

app.post("/LUNProvisionning", function (request, response) {
    console.log(request.body.serveur);
    console.log(request.body.volumetrie);
    console.log(request.body.type);
    response.render("\LUNProvisionning.html");
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Running on Port 8080');
});
```

It should simply redirect to my other page but it doesn't work.

when i go on this website : http://localhost:8080/LUNProvisionning my page is correctly shown.

thank you!

Comment: `app.set('view engine', 'html');` this is the line which is complaining. use some template engine https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: I don't want to use EJS or PUG. I am trying to use only HTML for now.

Comment: not sure if there's one for only `html`. with `ejs` you can do something like `app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile)`, other packages might have similar functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a templating engine just remove those line and use sendFile (if you don't have a templating engine, you can't use response.render) :

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
```

Comment: Well that was simple. thanks for the answer. worked perfectly.